# How to make toast message with two button pressed

Tags: android, toast

How to make toast message with 2 button... if pressing two buttons then toast message... please help me...

Comment: Simultaneously? In sequence...?

Comment: I want to create a program of learning letters.
for example: Writing "ANT"
we have the keys A, N and T

if the user presses the button A, N and T then the message "You are right"
if you just hit the A button the message "You are wrong"

I am confused .. how to make a toast message using the button more than one
help please on .. I'm working on a thesis. and still new to android. I am from Indonesia. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toast will never receive focus. The idea is to be as unobtrusive as possible.
see this link:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html

You might want to use alertdialog rather than toast.
see this link:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog

Comment: I want to create a program of learning letters.
for example: Writing "ANT"
we have the keys A, N and T

if the user presses the button A, N and T then the message "You are right"
if you just hit the A button the message "You are wrong"

I am confused .. how to make a toast message using the button more than one
help please on .. I'm working on a thesis. and still new to android. I am from Indonesia. thank you

Comment: You can use editText for user input then use the button just like "submit answer" in other apps. Set an OnClickListener to your button then do some validation if the submitted is same to the given word. If the word is not equal then toast that the answer is wrong else toast that the answer is correct

Hope this helps you, Thanks